# Difficulty Generating Natural Responses with GPT when Using Context in Prompts

Tags: langchain

I am writing a prompt that instructs the model to act like a shopkeeper and use the context to answer the questions. The only problem it has is that it lacks the ability to produce natural responses to simple statements like "Ok," "Thanks," "Bye," etc. It just keeps on using the context for answering such statements.

This is what my prompt looks like:

```
You are a shopping assistant.\
You sell footwear, clothing and accessories.\
You are friendly.\
You can hold human-like conversation.\
You detect the language of the Question.\
You translate your final response in the detected language.\
You consult the Context properly before answering the Question.\
If you do not have the product, say you do not have it and recommend something similar.\
You do not hallucinate.\
You do not give incorrect answers.\
Briefly introduce yourself if the Question contains greeting.\
Say 'Thanks for shopping with us' if the statement is saying anything along the lines of 'Thank you' or 'Ok' or 'Okay' or is showing any appreciation.\
Say 'Goodbye' if the statement is saying anything along the lines of 'see you later' or 'bye'.
When the customer is ready to purchase, help him with ordering steps
Question:\"""
{question}
\"""
Context:\"""
{context}
\"""
Helpful Answer:"""
```

These are the chains that I am using:

```
# Create LLM models from OpenAI
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
streaming_llm = OpenAI(
    streaming=True,
    model='text-davinci-003',
    callback_manager=CallbackManager([
        StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]),
    verbose=True,
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=200
)

# Create question generation chain using LLMChain
question_generator = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=condense_question_prompt
)

# Create question answering chain using load_qa_chain
doc_chain = load_qa_chain(
    llm=streaming_llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    prompt=qa_prompt
)

# Create ConversationalRetrievalChain
chatbot = ConversationalRetrievalChain(
    retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(search_type="mmr"),
    return_source_documents=True,
    combine_docs_chain=doc_chain,
    question_generator=question_generator
)
```

I am certain that the problem lies in the prompt and not in the code.
I would greatly appreciate your assistance in making the prompt better and more versatile.

Comment: add the code that supports your observation. That would ease folks to debug and recreate.